# How to create a pivot table from a given dataframe?

Tags: pandas, seaborn, pivot-table

I have imported the `tips` data set from seaborn and tried to find the maximum bill amount for lunch and dinner on Saturday and Sunday.

I tried below code but get an error:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=df['total_bill'], index=df['day'],
               columns=df['time'], aggfunc='max')
```

Comment: `pd.pivot_table(df, values='total_bill',index='day', columns='time', aggfunc='max')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get data for index as 'Sat' and 'Sun' you can use loc along with the pivot you created.

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='total_bill',index='day', 
               columns='time', aggfunc='max').loc[['Sat', 'Sun']]
```